# PHP dynamic Pivot table not outputting value

Tags: php, pivot

I having been working on trying to get this script to work, the SQL query works fine and returns the value from the Response field with the parameters 34 for class_id and 113 for Topic_id but will not echo 'Response' into the columns. It does echo the names correctly but with a blank grid.

```
<?php
$class_id = 34;
$Topic_id = 113;

// Actual Query that outputs all the desired results correctly on MySQL
$query = "SELECT Homework.Homework_title, Class_List.Class_List_id, Class_List.class_id, Class_List.user_id, Homework_Assign.Homework_assign_id, Homework_Assign.Completed, Homework_Assign.Response, Homework_Assign.Class_List_id, Homework_Assign.Homework_id, User_Accounts_.user_id, User_Accounts_.firstname, User_Accounts_.lastname, Homework.Topic_id FROM Homework, Class_List, Homework_Assign, User_Accounts_ WHERE Class_List.Class_List_id=Homework_Assign.Class_List_id AND User_Accounts_.user_id=Class_List.user_id AND Class_List.class_id=? AND Homework.Homework_id=Homework_Assign.Homework_id AND Homework.Topic_id=? ORDER BY User_Accounts_.firstname ASC";

// Prepared Statments
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $class_id, $Topic_id);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Fetch data and build the pivot table
    $pivotData = array();
    $columns = array();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $pivotData[$row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname']][$row['Homework_assign_id']]['Response'] = $row['Response'];
        $columns[$row['Homework_id']] = $row['Homework_title'];
    }

    // Sort columns in ascending order by Homework_id
    ksort($columns);

    $columns = array_values($columns);

    // Display the pivot table
    echo '<table border="1"><tr><th></th>';

    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        echo '<th>' . $column . '</th>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';

    foreach ($pivotData as $rowKey => $rowData) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . $rowKey . '</td>';

        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            echo '<td>';
            if (isset($rowData[$column]['Response'])) {
                echo 'Response: ' . $rowData[$column]['Response'];
            } else {
                echo 'No response';
            }
            echo '</td>';
        }

        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
} else {
    echo "No results found.";
}
?>
```

Comment: `echo 'Response: ' . $rowData[$column]['Response'];` - can't make sense of that; `$column` will be the individual `$row['Homework_title']` values. But `$rowData` was set in `$pivotData` using the `$row['Homework_assign_id']` as key, so how are those two supposed to match now?

Comment: @CBroe How do I match the two please?

Comment: That's a bit hard to say, without even knowing what your data looks like. Since you apparently want to generate a table column for each homework title (resp. ID), you should probably group your $pivotData on the second level by the same criterion.